# Daemon to check the status of a 3D Printer across the network (idle/printing)

Tags: networking, printing, tcp, daemon

I would like to develop a little daemon software that will be run on a Windows computer.

I am trying to know if a 3D printer connected through the network (TCP/IP assigned through DHCP) is currently printing, or is it idle.

I believe the fact that it's a 3D Printer is of little interest here, and the same would apply to a regular inkjet/laser network printer.

I have some background in TCP/IP, Networking but very little knowledge about drivers and devices status querying.

Is there anyway to identify packets from a specific device inside the network?
Is this the way to go (listening to packets passing through the network), or is there an easier way?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but OctoPrint (http://octoprint.org) gives you a web based interface for your 3d printer. Then you could pretty easily scrap the web page to see if it's busy or not, and you just need to be able to make an HTTP connection and parse HTML. That might be an easier path.

Comment: While it's an excellent solution for open-source based printers, it would not work in my case, as I am working with industrial-grade printers that have proprietary software.
Thanks a lot though